# Polly waits the thread for an indefinite amount of time on .NET Framework 4.6.1 when called from a Web API project

Tags: c#, .net, polly

.NET Version: .NET Framework 4.6.1 
Polly Version: 7.2.2

On .NET Framework 4.6.1 when using a Web API project Polly will wait the thread the request is running in for an indefinite amount of time, causing there to never be a response back to the client that called it. Calling the same method from a console app will work just fine.

This was tested using a freshly created solution in Visual Studio 'ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)'.
I also tried this same code in .NET 5 and this issue is not present, it only happens on .NET Framework 4.6.1.

**Code to reproduce the problem**:

PolicyContainer.cs:

```cs
public class PolicyContainer
{
    public IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> CircutBreakerPolicy { get; set; }

    public PolicyContainer()
    {
        SetCircutBreakerPolicy();
    }

    private void SetCircutBreakerPolicy()
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Normally these values would be set by a config file, hardcoded for this example. //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // 0.5 means 50% of requests must fail before the circut breaks
        double failureThreshold = 0.5;

        // 60 means only the most recent 60 seconds are considered for breaking the circut
        double samplingDuration = 60;

        // 10 means at least this many calls must pass through the circut within the samplingDuration before breaking the circut
        int minimumThroughput = 10;

        // 60 means the circut will be broken for 60 seconds after the threshold is met
        double durationOfBreak = 60;
            
            
        CircutBreakerPolicy = Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(result => !result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(failureThreshold,
                                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(samplingDuration),
                                            minimumThroughput,
                                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(durationOfBreak),
                                            OnBreak,
                                            OnReset,
                                            OnHalfOpen);
    }

    private void OnBreak(DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage> response, TimeSpan timespan, Context context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Circut Broken");
    }

    private void OnReset(Context context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Circut Reset");
    }

    private void OnHalfOpen()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Circut Half-Open");
    }
}
```

PollyTestRequest.cs:

```cs
public class PollyTestRequest
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // If set to true the Web API will never return a response, though any other type of project works fine. //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private const bool USE_POLLY = true;

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        PolicyContainer policyContainer = new PolicyContainer();
        HttpResponseMessage response;

        if (USE_POLLY)
        {
            // Does not work in a Web API application. 
            // I stepped through the decompiled code this calls and it will arrive at a "public static bool Wait(object obj, int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext)" method.
            // Inside this method there is a call to "ObjWait(exitContext, millisecondsTimeout, obj)", however the debugger will not decompile this method so the debugging session will stop if you try to step into it.
            // The 'millisecondsTimeout' variable passed here will be "-1" and the 'exitContext' will be "null". I believe that this is what is hanging the thread indefinitely.
            // Its very strange though, calling this from a Console app, it will work fine, but from a Web API application it will hang indefinitely.
            response = await policyContainer.CircutBreakerPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
                            async token => await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"), new StringContent(""), token), 
                            CancellationToken.None
                        );
        }
        else
        {
            // Works perfectly fine in both Web API and Console Apps
            response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"), new StringContent("")).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

TestController.cs:

```cs
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("testRoute")]
    public IHttpActionResult TestGetRoute()
    {
        var response = PollyTestRequest.Send().Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd also like to add that I created a GitHub issue on the Polly project for this as well, in case this is a bug with it. If I get a response there before here I will add an answer with any info I receive. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/868

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your bug:

```
var response = PollyTestRequest.Send().Result;
```

[Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html); in situations like ASP.NET (pre-Core), it can cause a deadlock.

The proper fix is to use [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> TestGetRoute()
{
  var response = await PollyTestRequest.Send();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that was pretty interesting to read, thanks for sharing your blog post! I'll try this out and see if it helps, thank you!

Comment: How would I go about getting the data out of the request if it is just `async` all the way down? At some point I do need to get the `.Result` for this to actually use the data. Another problem with this is that there are methods in the call stack which use `out` parameters, which do not work with `async`. 

Do you have any other suggestions? 
I've tried a few things to get around this threading issue and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Nevermind, ignore the end of my previous comment. I was able to figure this out: 

`var response = Task.Run(async () => await PollyTestRequest.Send()).Result;`

Not the prettiest solution, but it at least works. Thanks!

Comment: @CorruptComputer You get the data by assigning a variable, e.g., `var response = await PollyTestRequest.Send();` As you convert to `async`, replace `out` parameters with tuples. [Do not use `Task.Run` or `Result` on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net).